# What type of phrase is 'not quite'?

Tags: phrases

I'd like to to know what type of phrase 'not quite' is.
My English Language teacher says it is a mitigated adverbial phrase, but I have no idea.
I'm pretty sure it is not mitigated, but partly adverbial due to the use of 'quite'.
Please help!

Comment: Googling, I find no mention of "mitigated adverbial phrase" or "mitigated adverb". I would call it an "adverbial phrase"; I don't know what your teacher means by "mitigated" here.

Comment: Yeah, I had no idea what she meant either. 
Thank you!

Comment: @Peter, maybe that teacher, using *mitigated*, means 'not entirely', so 'not quite', in her/his opinion, would be a 'not entirely adverbial phrase'; who can tell, who know?

Comment: _Not quite_ is a [hedged](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedge_(linguistics)) [quantifier](http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOfLinguisticTerms/WhatIsAQuantifier.htm). It indicates that quantity or quality does not reach a minimum level, though it is close to that level. It's used for processes in action, and refers to increasing the level of the quantified item to reach the minimum during the process. "Not yet; not yet, keep on; not quite, just a little bit more; OK, that's it."

Comment: @John Lawler New terminiology! Would it be a hedged quantifier in the context of the sentence 'you've not quite got the letters the right way round'

Comment: It can tone down a verb (_were not quite collapsing_) or an adjective (_not quite full_).

Comment: Hedges are very common. I recommend you read George Lakoff's paper on the subject from CLS 8. [The handout to the paper is here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/lakoffhedgesCLS8.pdf).

Comment: @John Lawler Ah I know what hedging is as I've stated in my analysis that is a form of hedging. It was the quantifier part that confused me..

Comment: I understand it now from reading back over.
Thank you for all of your responses! :)

Answer (score 2):

From John Lawler's comment:

> *Not quite* is a [hedged](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedge_(linguistics)) [quantifier](http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOfLinguisticTerms/WhatIsAQuantifier.htm). It indicates that quantity or quality does not reach a minimum level, though it is close to that level. It's used for processes in action, and refers to increasing the level of the quantified item to reach the minimum during the process. "Not yet; not yet, keep on; not quite, just a little bit more; OK, that's it."